# Classification of simply connected open sets of $\mathbb{R}^n $ modulo diffeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

Does that classification exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation becomes much more complicated in higher dimensions. Already in dimension $3$ there are uncountably many simply connected (even contractible) non homeomorphic open subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

See for example [this](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1962-102-02/S0002-9947-1962-0137105-X/S0002-9947-1962-0137105-X.pdf) paper in which the following theorem is proved:

> **Theorem 2:** There exist uncountably many contractible open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^3$, no two of which are homeomorphic. Hence, there are uncountably many different ways to express $\mathbb{R}^4$ as the product of a 3-manifold and a line.

This happen even restricting to **contractible** open subsets: if you consider **simply connected** open subsets there are even more examples, i.e. $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\cup_i\ p_i$ where $p_i$ are points.

If you consider dimension $4$ the situation is even more critical, see for example [**small exotic $\mathbb{R}^4s$**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_R4#Small_exotic_R4s): in this case you have even open subsets which are **homeomorphic** to a ball, but which are **not diffeomorphic**.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. Take as an example $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{ 0\}$. This is simply connected, but it is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$.